# Phoenix framework - assets don't update without running mix phx.digest

Tags: phoenix-framework, assets, brunch

After changing an asset (a css or js) file I see in the logs that the change was noticed and compiled, and the browser also auto-reloads.

```
[debug] Live reload: priv/static/js/app.js
10:53:15 - info: compiled MyComponent.jsx and 2095 cached files into 2 
files in 2.3 sec
```

However, it doesn't appear that the assets in `/priv/static` were actually updated. I can only see my change in the browser once I run `mix phx.digest`, and hard refresh the browser.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

---

Using:

- Phoenix 1.3
- brunch 2.10.7

config/dev.exs:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Web.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  code_reloader: true,
  check_origin: false,
  watchers: [node: ["node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch", "watch", "--stdin",
                cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)]]

# Watch static and templates for browser reloading.
config :my_app, MyApp.Web.Endpoint,
  live_reload: [
    patterns: [
      ~r{priv/static/.*(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$},
      ~r{priv/gettext/.*(po)$},
      ~r{lib/my_app/web/views/.*(ex)$},
      ~r{lib/my_app/web/templates/.*(eex)$}
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR — If you don't set the `cache_static_manifest` setting on your endpoint, it won't generate versioned URLs.

So, I know I'm about three years late here, but I recently figured this out.  I discovered that merely setting the `cache_static_manifest` value in the Endpoint config will cause it to use the digest in any mode.  (This **is** documented, but not in a way that seemed particularly clear to me.)

Now, you might be thinking "But I didn't set that in `dev` mode."  I thought that, too, until I realized that I had written a naive `config/runtime.exs`.

At the time, I had been focused on configuring things a runtime when running a release, but completely forgot that it configures things even when **not** running in a release.  Once I made it conditional, everything was fine.

Example:

```
if Config.config_env == :production do
  config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint, cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and for me it helped to manually remove the `static` folder with `rm -rf priv/static` and to restart the server with `mix phx.server`. Afterwards the hot reloading worked without having to manually run `mix phx.digest` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is that the Endpoint module (`lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex`) is setting `Plug.Static` to use compressed assets:

```elixir
defmodule MyAppWeb.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :my_app_web

  plug Plug.Static,
    # ...
    gzip: true,
```

Then, if a release has been built from within the project directory and the gzipped assets are still present when developing, they will be served instead of the newly-saved, non-compressed assets.

To avoid this:

`config/dev.exs`:

```
config :my_app, :environment, :dev
```

`config/test.exs`:

```
config :my_app, :environment, :test
```

`config/prod.exs`:

```
config :my_app, :environment, :prod
```

`lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex`:

```elixir
defmodule MyAppWeb.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :my_app_web

  in_prod = Application.get_env(:my_app, :environment) == :prod

  plug Plug.Static,
    # ...
    gzip: in_prod,
```